# With the retry options in durable functions, what happens after the last attempt?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, dead-letter, azure-durable-functions

I'm using a durable function that's triggered off a queue. I'm sending messages off the queue to a service that is pretty flaky, so I set up the RetryPolicy. Even still, I'd like to be able to see the failed messages *even if* the max retries has been exhausted.

Do I need to manually throw those to a dead-letter queue (and if so, it's not clear to me how I know when a message has been retried any number of times), or will the function naturally throw those to some kind of dead-letter/poison queue?

Answer (score 2):

When an activity fails in Durable Functions, an exception is marshalled back to the orchestration with `FunctionFailedException` thrown. It doesn't matter whether you used automatic retry or not - at the very end, the whole activity fails and it's up to you to handle the situation. As per documentation:

```
try
{
    await context.CallActivityAsync("CreditAccount",
        new
        {
            Account = transferDetails.DestinationAccount,
            Amount = transferDetails.Amount
        });
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // Refund the source account.
    // Another try/catch could be used here based on the needs of the application.
    await context.CallActivityAsync("CreditAccount",
        new
        {
            Account = transferDetails.SourceAccount,
            Amount = transferDetails.Amount
        });
}
```

The only thing retry changes is handling the transient error(so you do not have to enable the safe route each time you have e.g. network issues).